# Shipping method not loaded

Tags: magento, magento2

Shipping methods are not loading and I have such a problem in logs. Anyone know what could be the reason?

`FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\AsynchronousOperations\Model\ConfigInterface in /home/www/magento-project/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111`

I cleaned the cache and redis but nothing helped. I was running full builds, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Describe which payment are you using?

Comment: @Jinesh sorry problem the problem appears before. When choosing a delivery method.

Comment: have you implement any theme?

Comment: yes i have a custom theme. But the problem most likely appeared after the upgrade to 2.2.8. It's possible that something is missing in the app / etc / di.xml?

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: is it possible to share di.xml file here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

Create di.xml file in frontend folder with the content below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\CopyConstructor\Composite"> <arguments> <argument name="constructors" xsi:type="array"> <item name="crossSell" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\CopyConstructor\CrossSell</item> <item name="upSell" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\CopyConstructor\UpSell</item> <item name="related" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\CopyConstructor\Related</item> <item name="catalog_inventory" xsi:type="string">Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Product\CopyConstructor\CatalogInventory</item> <item name="downloadable" xsi:type="string">Magento\Downloadable\Model\Product\CopyConstructor\Downloadable</item> </argument> </arguments> </type> <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier"> <arguments> <argument name="copyConstructor" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\CopyConstructor\Composite</argument> </arguments> </type> </config>
```

Comment: unfortunately the delivery method still doesn't load